# How to transform a queryset instance to dictionary Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

In order to optimize my function, I would like to transform a queryset to a dictionary and stock it in cache. Here is my instance and the output:

```
 nodes = Node.objects.select_related().all()

<QuerySet [<Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF 
)>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, 
<Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: 
Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : 
No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No 
name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name 
of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( 
Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( 
Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( 
Network IDF )>, <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>, '...(remaining elements 
truncated)...']>
```

For example :

```
nodes.get(node_id=7223004840) is <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF )>
```

I would like my dictionary contains each of my node_id with the associated instance. For example:

```
{7223004840 : <Node: Node : No name of ( Network IDF ), etc}
```

I don't want to use get :

```
 {7223004840 : nodes.get(node_id=7223004840), etc}
```

because it will hit so many time the database. For information I have more than 77 000 rows and 20 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nodes = Node.objects.select_related().all()
nodes_list = [
    {item.id: item} for item in nodes
]
```

It will hit only once to DB.

Comment: Indeed this solution works. But I thought, there exist a solution without looping. Lots of thanks